# Put multiple boxplots per group stratified

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a question on how to stratify making multiple box plots per group. This is what I have for a sample code

```
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$vs <- as.character(as.numeric(mtcars$vs))

y6 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=vs,y=hp)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = vs),outlier.shape=NA, size=1, width = 0.6, fatten = 1) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(x=vs, y=hp, pch = factor(cyl)), position=position_jitter(width=.1, height=0), size = 2) + 
  scale_shape_manual(name ="X", values = c(1,2,3))  + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 350))
```

[image]

This is what I obtain from the graph. I hope to stratify the graphs per X axis by the legend making a total of 6 box plots (3 per X axis; 3 for "1" and 3 for "2"). Is there a way to do this? I have attached an image of it below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code for you:

```
library(ggplot2)
  
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=vs,y=hp,fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(cyl)),outlier.shape=NA, size=1, width = 0.6, fatten = 1) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 350))
```

[image]

I have used `fill=` argument in `ggplot()` to split/group the data by column `cyl`.

If you look closer at `mtcars` data and your plot, you actually do not have 3 unique values of `cyl` for `vs = 1`, just two (`cyl` 4 & 8)..Therefore you get total of 5 boxes

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are asking?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(vs, hp)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~cyl) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

There are no values for `vs` when `cyl==8` and only one value for `vs` when `cyl==4`.

```
table(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$vs)
#    0  1
# 4  1 10
# 6  3  4
# 8 14  0
```

If you are a fan of colouring the plots, you can do it with the `fill` parameter.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(vs, hp, fill=as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~cyl) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]